# Why are my comments closed?

Tags: comments

I have a simple [site](http://golfbravo.net) with a few pages plus a [blog](http://golfbravo.net/blog). For some reason, the blog posts state **comments are closed** and I can't figure out why. I want to open the comments on all blog posts (and not offer comments on pages).

In the "edit post" screen, the "Comments" section just states "No comments yet." but doesn't offer any way to turn them on.

In settings>discussion, I have these:

> ON Comment author must fill out name and e-mail
>   OFF Users must be registered and logged in to comment
>   OFF Automatically close comments on articles older than (14) days
>   ON Enable threaded (nested) comments levels (5) deep
>   ON Break comments into pages with (50) top level comments per page and ...
>
> OFF Before a comment appears An administrator must always approve the comment
>   ON Comment author must have a previously approved comment
>
> ON Hold a comment in the queue if it contains (1) or more links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried go to "Posts" and checked the box next to the title and in the dropdown "Buld Actions" choose Edit and then apply, Comments and in the dropdown "Allow".

And also have added the screen in the post edit area on the tab in the header called "Screen Options" and checked the field called: Discussion?

And in settings->Discussion have you enabled "Allow people to post comments on new articles"?

Comment: 1) +1: Your first paragraph helped fix it for the existing posts! I still need to change the default setting to allow comments though - any advice?

Comment: 2) I'm sorry but I don't understand your second paragraph. In the "edit post" screen, I don't see anything called "screen options" nor "discussion". What did you mean?

Comment: If you editing a single post you have a tab in the right upper corner called: "Screen Options". Mark the box "Discussion" then you can turn on/off discussion on posts. 
And in settings-> discussion have you enabled "Allow people to post comments on new articles"

Comment: **D'OH!** The setting "Allow people to post comments on new articles" was off...! Problem solved!! Thanks also for the help on the tab, that was so well hidden that I didn't see it :-)

Comment: Yeah, thats an easy thing to miss, Glad it works for you now!